# Struggling to get correct css formatting on nest ul list

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling with this, I'd like my first li to have a round bullet and then the nested li's to have an indented square bullet. My CSS trying to do this is below, default styling of my page is not putting any bullets in place.

Can someone help?

```
<ul>

    <li>Simplification of a complex purchase category
        <ul>
            <li>Meet local regulatory compliance </li>
            <li>Subitem 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Final list item</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul:first-child {
    list-style-type:circle;
}

li:first-child {
    list-style-type:square;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
    list-style-type:square;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
li {
    list-style-type:circle;
}

li li {
    list-style-type:square;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use classes on your  tags to set the list-style-type.

HTML

```
 <ul class="round">
        <li>Simplification of a complex purchase category
            <ul class="square">
                <li>Meet local regulatory compliance </li>
                <li>Subitem 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Final list item</li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.round {
    list-style-type:bullet;
}

.square {
    list-style-type:square;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8H9JA/

Comment: I try to make it a practice to let classes in my markup say "what it is" and not "how it looks" e.g. `red` or `round`. Should you decide later that you want to change `li.round` to a different list type, you have to change it in both your markup AND in your CSS.

Comment: You are right but that is just a matter of semantics. For the sake of the demo I changed the class names to be easily recognizable. Of course you could also call your classes: main-menu-list and sub-menu-list. Therefor it says what it is, not what it looks like and you only have to change the css when you want to change the visual appeal.

Comment: Good stuff. Just put that comment there for posterity. :)